# Data not evaluated when my directive controller run using "Controller As" syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a simple Angular JS directive:

- It receives a number X
- It calculates the next and the previous numbers of X

Here is the directive code

```
(function() {

'use strict';

  angular
    .module('main')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

  /** @ngInject */
  function myDirective() {
    return {
      bindToController: true,
      controller: MyController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        number: '<'
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-directive.template.html',
    };
  }

  /** @ngInject */
  function MyController($scope, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    // calculate(); // previous and next = NaN
    // $timeout(calculate, 1); // Works
    vm.watch = $scope.$watch('vm.number', calculate); //Works

    function calculate() {
      vm.previous = vm.number - 1;
      vm.next = vm.number + 1;
      vm.watch();
    }
  }
})();
```

Here is how I call it

```
<my-directive number="7"></my-directive>
```

---

My problem is:

- When controller runs, the number passed to the directive haven't been evaluated yet

After research, I found 2 solutions, but they don't look nice:

1. Use the `$timeout` service in MyController
2. Use the `$scope.$watch` service in MyController

I think the solution (1) may fall sometimes if it takes longer to evaluate the data.

As I don't need to watch the data, using solution (2) I remove the watch after the function `calculate` is executed, but using a watch here don't feel right.

---

So, there is a better solution for this? Or solutions (2) is just fine for that?

Comment: try making this a component, and using `vm.$oninit()` maybe?

Comment: Okay. I didn't know about components. I took some time to read it in [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). I will redo this directive as a component. Later I will comment here the results

Comment: @Claies It has worked like a charm. I update the post with a plunker with the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user Claies has suggested, I created a component for that, and it worked perfectly.

Here is the component declaration

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('main')
    .component('myComponent', {
      templateUrl: 'my-component.template.html',
      controller: MyController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindings: {
        number: '<',
        goNext: '&',
        goPrevious: '&'
      }
    });

  /** @ngInject */
  function MyController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.$onInit = onInit;
    vm.$onChanges = onNumberChange;

    vm.onNext = onNext;
    vm.onPrevious = onPrevious;

    function onInit() {
      calculate();
    }

    function onNumberChange(changesObj) {
      if (changesObj.number) {
        calculate();
      }
    }

    function onNext() {
      vm.goNext();
    }

    function onPrevious() {
      vm.goPrevious();
    }

    function calculate() {
      vm.previous = vm.number - 1;
      vm.next = vm.number + 1;
    }

  }
})();
```

To test the `$onChanges` functionality from the component, I added an `add` and a `subtract` actions.

And here is how I used the component in the HTML page

```
<my-component number="vm.number" go-next="vm.goNext()" go-previous="vm.goPrevious()"></my-component>
```

The complete example I made can be found in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QvQ9yFDaTCGgWW2A5lAA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your module declaration.

This

```
angular
.module('main')
```

should be this

```
angular
.module('main', [])
```

The [requires] argument is needed when declaring a new module.

Comment: I have made the module declaration in another file.

The problem I have here is that the variable `number` passed to the directive don't exist when MyController run.